# Finding a divisor $d^n$ of $a^n+b^n$ such that $d\mid a+b$ but $d^n\nmid a+b$

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let us suppose that $d\mid (a+b)$, where $\mid$ means "divides", and such that $d>1$, $n>1$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Could it be proved that $d^n\mid a^n+b^n$ only if $d^n\mid a+b$? If false, could you show some counterexample?

The question comes from the observation that $$a+b\mid a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1} \forall k \in \mathbb N$$ However, I have not been able to find any power $d^n$ dividing $a^n+b^n$ and not dividing also $a+b$.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

From the counterexample provided, I have noticed that for $a+b=p^{k}$, $p$ being some odd prime number, it holds that $p^{k+1}\mid a^p+b^p$. This result can be derived both from the observation provided in the OP, and Fermat's Little Theorem, and provides a family of counterexamples setting $d=n=p$ and $a+b=p^{p-1}$. Thus, I think it would be interesting to show some counterexample such that $d\neq n$

Comment: $a= 3, b = 4, d = 5, n = 2$.

Comment: @WhatsUp 5 doesn't divide 7

Comment: @Exodd I only saw the sentence *Could it be proved that $d^n∣a^n+b^n$ only if $d^n∣a+b$?* Anyway $a = 8, b = 1, d = 3, n = 3$ should be another example.

Comment: I think [Lifting the exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) sheds some light to this problem. Assume that $d$ is a prime number $p$ (might as well look at this one prime factor of $d$ at a time). Assume further that $n$ is odd, so that $b^n=-(-b)^n$. Then lifting the exponent lemma says that highest power $p^m$ that divides $a^n+b^n$ has the exponent $m=\ell+k$, where $p^\ell$ is the highest power that divides $a+b$ and $p^k$ is the highest power that divides $n$. The problem is that $k$ is always small in comparison to $n$.

Comment: (cont'd) This places severe constraints on how this can happen. $\ell$ and $k$ need to combine (as in Don Thousand's example). In particular, $\ell$ must be relatively close to $n$, but need not be exactly $n$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for sharing the Lemma, I did not know it, really interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried $$a=8,b=1,n=3,d=3$$

Comment: Yes, we need $d^{n-\epsilon}$ to be a factor of $a+b$ for some relatively small $\epsilon$. I tried to explain this in a comment under main.

Comment: @DonThousand thanks!!